Can I use orphaned OOTB brushes?
In my Blender files, I noticed I only have one brush for Texture Paint (and probably other modes). In view orphans, it looks like there are a lot brush presets. Can I add them to my set of brushes and use them? I tried to drag it onto my brush tool panel, but that did not work.

Also curious, if anyone knows, why they end up orphaned? I guess because they are not used; but doesn't make sense they get orphaned for lack of use when they were not offered to be used before orphaning.
